# Align button in col-sm-4 on small devices

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Please, see http://jsfiddle.net/eDNH5/201/

The **read-more** below is centered with large displays (3 columns), but if you narrow the window to simulate a smartphne (1 column) it is aligned to the left. How can I make it centered?

```
<div class="col-sm-4"></div>
<a id="readmore" class="read-more col-sm-4" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion<?php echo $track->Id; ?>" href="#collapse<?php echo $track->Id; ?>">Show More</a>
<div class="col-sm-4"></div>

.read-more {
    background-color:#eee;
    color:#666;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    padding:10px 0;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.read-more:hover {
    color:#333;
    background-color:#ddd;
}

.read-more:a visited {
    color:#666;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have content *between* columns? That's about as useful as a chive between one's teeth. :-)

Comment: I'm not sure what's unclear about my question. You have a grid structure with columns, and you have an anchor that lies outside those columns. Why? Here's a demo (with the proper Bootstrap files loaded) that shows this. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/jmzLvtzk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restructure your markup and add `.text-center`

```
<div class="col-sm-4"></div>
<div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
  <a id="readmore" class="read-more" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion<?php echo $track->Id; ?>" href="#collapse<?php echo $track->Id; ?>">Show More</a>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4"></div>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/v28r6rbr/)